# Regex to split around a word

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to get the `String.split()` to do what I would like it to do.

I have an Input of a string of words separated by spaces. Some words have a special function. They look something like this: "special:word".

The input string I am using to test my regex looks like this:

`String str = "Hello wonderful special:world what a great special:day";`

The result I would like to get from `str.split(regex)` is an array with the words "world" and "day";

I tried doing it with lookahead `(?<=special\:)(\w+)` but this splits the string at the words I am looking for. How do I inverse this expression to get the result I am looking for and what exactly do lookaheads and reverse lookaheads do?

Comment: I wouldn't use `split` for this. Use `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `split` in this case would create few problems:

1. overcomplicated regex to match part that we should split on

   ```
   Hello wonderful special:world what a great special:day
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. after split your first element would be empty string `""` because split doesn't trim first empty elements like it does in last empty elements so your result would be

   ```
   ["", "world", "day"]
   ```

To avoid this use more intuitive approach: instead of finding everything that is NOT part that you want, find only part that you are interested in. To do this use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes. Here is example of how you can find all your special words:

```
String str = "Hello wonderful special:world what a great special:day";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w+:(\\w+)\\b");//word after : will be in group 1
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()){//this will iterate over all found substrings
    //here we can use found substrings
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
world
day
```

Comment: but can't you say: get all words between the word after a ':' and a ':'?

Comment: @JNK `all words between the word after a ':' and a ':'` but at start you don't have any `special:word` so how would it match `Hello wonderful special:`? Also such expression would mean "words that have `:someWord` before and `:` after it", but at the same time you don't want to include `someWord` in match because you don't want this token to be be removed by split. So you will have to use look-around mechanisms, like `(?<=:\\w+).*?(?=:)` but in Java you have to set max length of look-behind so `\\w+` will not compile. Pattern/Matcher solution is better for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Pattern` and `Matcher`

```
    String searchPattern = "Hello wonderful special:world what a great special:day";
    Pattern pa = Pattern.compile(":[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
    Matcher ma = pa.matcher(searchPattern);
    while(ma.find()){
        System.out.println(ma.group().replaceFirst(":",""));    
    }
```

*output*:

```
world
day
```

By using `split()` we can do as:

```
    String searchPattern1 = "Hello wonderful special:world what a great special:day";
    for(String i:searchPattern1.split("\\s")){
        if(i.contains(":")){
            System.out.println(i.split[1]);
        }
    }
```

Here also we get the same output as above.

Answer (score 0):

use patter and matcher, simple example

```
public static ArrayList<String> parseOut(String s)
{
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String regex = "([:])(\\w+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()){
        list.add(matcher.group().substring(1));
    }
    return list;
}
```